# Phone Stolen and want to know if it was erased or a google error

Tags: applications, samsung, gmail, google, lost-phone

My phone was stolen a week ago. I went home to log into my Google account in order to erase my device through Android "Find My Device". There was a check sign next to the erase, but it is still showing up on my account. I watched videos that told the owner that the phone was factory reset and I think my phone has not. Does this mean the thief has access to everything?

Comment: Were you able to see the location of the device when you tried to erase? After erase, does the screen still look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7MCw.jpg)?

Comment: "still showing up on my account" what do you mean by that?

Comment: My results said now that it can not contact the device and the last location that appeared was the area where I got robbed from. It says my phone has not been online since then. I tried erasing and it had a check ,but it did not email me or say the device went into a factory reset.

Comment: The "still showing up on my account" part was about find my device because some people say after the device has been wiped successfully the device will no longer show up in the android device manager window when you log in using your google account.

Answer (score 2):

When you press on the *erase* option on the *find my device,* page, it tells you "If your device is offline, erasing will being when it next comes online" This is because Google cannot erase your device if it cannot connect to it.

The check mark you see, tells you that you put it into "erase mode" but it will only take place when it's online.

Had the device been online when you tried to erase it, it would have told you that it's online, and you would have seen the actual location.

I must conclude that the thief turned the phone off as soon as he got it. He could then put it through factory reset, or access your data while in airplane mode.

If you had a lock on your phone, the chances of him getting passed it, are very small. But If you did not have any lock on it, then he could have access to your data, and there's not much you can do about that.